# a+ and a mode with fopen()

Tags: php, fopen, mode, feof, ftell

According to the manual, if you select `a/a+` mode in the `fopen()` function, the file pointer will be placed at the end.

But why do I get 0 using the `ftell()` and the `feof()` still returns `false`? If the file pointer is at the end.

e.g:

```
$handle=fopen("./file.txt","w");
fwrite($handle,1234567890);
fclose($handle);
$handle=fopen("./file.txt","a+");
echo getc($handle);
fclose($handle);
```

I got 1, but shouldn't I get 0 if the file pointer is placed at the end?

Comment: Have you tried to actually write a string to the file instead of an integer?

Comment: Yes, I have. But the result is still the same.

Comment: using the ftell() might be a bad idea. But if I choose a+ mode,  why fgetc() still return the first character of the file? a+ mode put the file pointer in the end.

Answer (score 3):

`a+` means, **read** from beginning, **write** to the end.

That's why you get a char back from the stream.

Internally you have two streams, `STDIN` and `STDOUT`.

Comment: but the file pointer is placed in the end. doesn't that affect the fread(), fgets()?

Comment: @ray: There is more than one file pointer, despite what PHP's abstraction makes you think.

Comment: It should be kept in mind that there is practically no use case where you want to read and write a file at the same time without beeing able to separate those steps, which is safer anyways.

Answer (score 2):

`"a"` - **Write only**. Opens and writes to the end of the file or creates a new file if it doesn't exist.

`"a+"` - **Read/Write**. Preserves file content by writing to the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Right there in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php), near the top:

> `ftell()` gives undefined results for append-only streams (opened with "a" flag).

Comment: using the ftell() might be a bad idea. But if I choose a+ mode, why fgetc() still return the first character of the file? a+ mode put the file pointer in the end

Comment: @ray: Probably a discrepancy between the internal read and write cursors. I guess PHP just _tries_ to keep them synched but doesn't go out of its way to detect when they begin life otherwise. When you open a file directly from POSIX in append mode, the write cursor is at the end _but the read cursor is at the start_.